# Backbone Collection from URL json

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

`[{"uniqueId":61,"content":"test","createTextDate":"time"}]`

this is `/data/commentList.json`

```
var Comment = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        uniqueId: null,
        createTextDate: null,
        content: null
    }
});
```

Model for Backbone Collection

```
var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Comment,

    url: function() {
        return '/data/commentList.json';
        },      

        parse: function(response) {
            return response.results;
        },
        sync: function(method, model, options) {
            var that = this;
            var params = _.extend({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: that.url(),
                processData: false
            }, options);

            return $.ajax(params);
        }
});
```

Backbone Collection

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#test'),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.collection = new List();
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function() {
                console.log("SUCESS");
                console.log(that.collection.toJSON());
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Failed to fetch!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Console log

`Failed to fetch!`

How to make Backbone Collection using jSON url?

Comment: why do you need `parse` and `sync`?

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul for get json from url

Comment: backbone model will automatically recognize it. It is json-ready. no need to parse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.results;
    },
```

Above code assumes your server returns

```
{"results": [comment1, comment2]}
```

You rarely need to override `sync` method.